# Is this a safe way of getting the time in milliseconds on IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() / 1000; I just wanted to make sure that it was precise, or if there was a better way of doing it.

Comment: This is not a duplicate as my question was not asked in that post.

Comment: Either `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()` or `NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()` will give you a `Double` that's as accurate as the system can provide. What are you trying to do?